# Fetching a variable inside a list in ROBOT Framework

Tags: robotframework, web-api-testing

Suppose the below is my response body

```
body={
  "message": {
    "Code": 26181,
    "rollnos": [
      {
        "ID": 1439173,
        "date_input": "2022-01-31 14:09:30.206748",
      }
    ],
    "start_date": "2022-01-31 00:00:00",
  }
}
```

I want to set the ID value in a variable.
I have tried the below but it did not work out.

```
  ${json_response}=  set variable    ${xyz.json()}
  
  ${temp}=  Set Variable    ${json_response['message']}
  
  ${value_1}=  Set Variable    ${temp['rollnos']}
  
  ${register_id} =  Set Variable    ${value_1["ID"]
```

Can someone please help where I went wrong in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `body` already as a dictionary you can use only the last 4 lines from the test example. I have included also the transformation from string to dictionary in case you need it:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Collections

Resource          robot/resources/environment_resources.robot

*** Variables ***
${body_temp}    {"message": {"Code": "26181", "rollnos": [{"ID": "1439173", "date_input": "2022-01-31 14:09:30.206748"}],"start_date": "2022-01-31 00:00:00"}}

*** Keywords ***
Converting a JSON File
    ${body}    evaluate  json.loads($body_temp)    json
    [Return]  ${body}

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    # Get body as dict
    ${body}=  converting a json file

    # Get the ID
    ${message} =    Get From Dictionary     ${body}    message
    ${rollnos} =    Get From Dictionary     ${message}    rollnos

    ${id} =   Get From Dictionary     ${rollnos}[0]    ID

    # Log the ID
    Log To Console    ID:${id}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone please help where I went wrong in this.

You are treating `${temp['rollnos']}` as a dictionary, but it is a list of dictionaries.

Instead of this:

```
${value_1}=  Set Variable    ${temp['rollnos']}

${register_id} =  Set Variable    ${value_1["ID"]
```

Do this, to get the ID of the first item in the dictionary:

```
${value_1}=  Set Variable    ${temp['rollnos'][0]}
#                                             ^^^
${register_id} =  Set Variable    ${value_1["ID"]}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, when you say:

> but it did not work out.

You don't mention what were the error messages.

This is my interpretation of your code:

```
  ${json_response}=  set variable    ${xyz.json()}
  # ${json_response} is now a dictionary with content: body=&{message}
  # So the next step would be: 
  ${temp}=  Set Variable    ${json_response['body']['message']}
  # And now we have: &{temp} = { Code:26181, &{rollnos}, ...
  # The next code will be correct
  ${value_1}=  Set Variable    ${temp['rollnos']}
  
  ${register_id} =  Set Variable    ${value_1['ID']
```

But you got the value of ID, and you wanted to Set it, so that is another question.

Comment: This looks like it has the same mistake as the OP: you're treating the `'rollnos'` value as a dictionary  but it's a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks.